# Pandas replace multiple columns only when missing or NA from other dataset

Tags: python, pandas

As a Minimum Working Example, I have two datasets with 2 keys [`col1` and `col2`] and multiple columns with data [columns starting with `z_`].

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ["A", "B"], 'z_col3': [3, np.nan], 'z_col4': [3, 4]} )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1': [1,2], 'col2': ["C", "B"], 'z_col3': [3, 4], 'z_col4': [3, 4]} )
```

[image: Data frames]

I want to do a merge where `df1` with missing values in the `z_` columns would get the values from `df2`. Is there any intelligent way to do so? This is a MWE so I have a quite large table with 50+ columns.

I tried the following but it yields an error:

```
df1[['z_col3','z_col4']] = df2[['col1','col2']].map(df2.set_index(['col1','col2'])[['z_col3','z_col4']])
```

Any idea on how to make it?

Comment: What does MWE mean?

Comment: Minimum Working Example... so like a very simplified version of the problem.

Comment: Check the [df.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) page in the pandas docs, You can also use [df.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using a for loop with `fillna()` after filtering for the specific columns. Remember you can use `fillna()` rather than merge:

```
for x in [x for x in df if x.startswith('z')]:
   df_1[x] = df_1[x].fillna(df_2[x])
```

Comment: Sorry I deselected the answer as I forgot to add in the MWE that the two dataframes are not equal in terms of combination of column ids [`col1` and `col2`]. So the loop does not work as some ids are missing in `df2`.

Comment: How would this work then? Please keep in mind your MWE should cover all logic aspects that you need help with. Otherwise we will solving your issue only to learn there is additional complexity not addressed in the question (and therefore not in the answer either). If z_col4 exists in df_1 but not in df_2 and viceversa for z_col5, should be there be any kind  of filling, or none?

Comment: yes, sorry I simplified too much. I will leave it as it is and try myself the route of the for loop. If I don't manage I can put other question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['col1','col2'], how='left')
```

and then use np.where:

```
import numpy as np
df1['z_col3_x'] = np.where(df1['z_col3_x'].isnull(), df1['z_col3_y'], df1['z_col3_x'])
df1['z_col4_x'] = np.where(df1['z_col4_x'].isnull(), df1['z_col4_y'], df1['z_col4_x'])
```

You can later rename the column names to their original names

To deal with many (50+) columns, you can use:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    if (col.startswith('z_') & col.endswith('_x')):
        col = col[:-2]
        df1[col + '_x'] = np.where(df1[col + '_x'].isnull(), df1[col + '_y'], df1[col + '_x'])
        df1.drop(col + '_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
        df1.rename(columns={col + '_x': col}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Op said they have more than 50 columns, this will require OP to copy-paste the same thing 50 times

Comment: @CeliusStingher - see updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

Given test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ["A", "B"], 'z_col3': [3, np.nan], 'z_col4': [3, 4]} )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ["C", "B"], 'z_col3': [3, 4], 'z_col4': [3, 4]} )

df1.set_index(['col1', 'col2'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['col1', 'col2'], inplace=True)

df1.update(df2)

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then simply print it:

```
print(df1)
```

Comment: Hi, is there a reason for merging and using combine first if you only need to fill the blank values?

Comment: You are right. Let me modify the code

Comment: @CeliusStingher Updated the code. But not sure.. Can you test it?

Comment: Careful, with update you will reassign the full dataframe, and not only NaNs. This is risky because of df_2 values will overwrite df_1 values regardless ofthem being NaN.